# User Email is nil (Octokit Github API)

Tags: ruby, github-api, octokit

Trying to make Octokit Github API calls using access token

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => 'xxxxxx')
```

I needed to fetch email address for a particular user apart from user whose access token is being used, so I'm trying to fetch email address for user 'abc'

```
user = client.user 'abc'
puts user.email
```

user email return nil, but able to see other details like repos_url, organisation etc.
I'm able to get the email address of the user whom I made connection using access token.

```
client.emails
```

this return the expected value.

So to fetch email address for a particular user we need to be authenticated with that user itself https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/4-stable/lib/octokit/client/users.rb#L293-L301, otherwise the email would just return nil.

Do we have an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Im not familiar with Octokit, however a user has the option of setting their email public or private in github. Can you verify with another account by setting their email public if you receive anything in `user.email`?

Comment: I have tried with multiple users who have their email address set as public, still getting nil for user.email